# VBA excel change value of multiple checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, activex

I have a big row of 250 ActiveX checkboxes of which I want to change the values all back from checked to unchecked, is there a way to put that in a macro?

checkbox names are just Checkbox3 to Checkbox253

Answer (score 3):

An easy way:

```
Private Sub UnchkAllBox()
    For i = 3 to 253
        Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

In this way, the names of the checkboxes are very important. Use it only you named your checkboxes orderly.

Other way:

```
Private Sub UnchkAllBox2()
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then Ctrl.Value = False
    Next Ctrl
End Sub
```

In this case, you don't have to concern the names. However, it will uncheck all checkboxes in your form.

Both methods mentioned are assuming all checkboxes were placed in a userform. For checkboxes in a worksheet, excel stores them in a OLEObjects collection instead of Controls. Therefore, the code should be re-written as below.

```
Private Sub UnChkAllBox()
    For i = 1 To 5
        OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub UnChkAllBox2()
    Dim Obj As OLEObject
    For Each Obj In Me.OLEObjects
        If TypeOf Obj.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then Obj.Object.Value = False
    Next Obj
End Sub
```

Comment: Both give an error:
First Way: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined". Second Way: "Compile Error: Invalid use of Me keyword"

Comment: It is indeed an activeX checkbox, I mixed stuff up doing 2 things at the same time. my appologies